# How do I count the times the word true was printed in my csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

The output that is generated is a column of true or false, I need to count how many times the word true was printed every 10 rows
In the code that I present, it reads csv files that are in one folder and prints them in another. In each of these csv's it contains two columns that were chosen when the dataframe was defined. In addition, two columns were added which, through the how_many_times function, count how many times the value meets the condition that I give it.

Example of my csv(original df has more rows):

```
In [1]: dff = pd.DataFrame([['20220901-00:00:00', 50.0335,False,True], ['20220901-00:00:01', 50.024,False,False], ['20220901-00:00:02', 50.021,False,False]], columns=['t', 'f','f<49.975','f>50.025'])
```

This is my code (I used .sum but it didn't work for what I needed):

```
import pandas as pd   
import numpy as np       
import glob   
import os  
all_files = glob.glob("C:/Users/Gamer/Documents/Colbun/Saturn/*.csv")   


file_list = []   
for i,f in enumerate(all_files):   
    df = pd.read_csv(f,header=0,usecols=["t","f"])
    how_many_times1= df.apply(lambda x: x['f'] < 49.975, axis=1).sum
    df['f<49.975']=how_many_times1
    how_many_times2= df.apply(lambda x: x['f'] > 50.025, axis=1).sum
    df['f>50.025']=how_many_times2
    df.to_csv(f'C:/Users/Gamer/Documents/Colbun/Saturn2/{os.path.basename(f).split(".")[0]}_ext.csv')
```

Comment: `sum` is a method, so you should do `xxx.sum()`.

Comment: How should the final df look like with the number of True 'each ten rows'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to count a value in a csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75350810/how-to-count-a-value-in-a-csv-file)

Comment: Claudio , I need to add another column which prints how many times the word true was written in the first 10 columns

Comment: @NickODell, It helped me with the problem I had when counting if f meets a certain condition but not for what I need now

Comment: You can now see how important it is to exactly specify the expected outcome. Now you speak about another column ... before about printing the sum. Hopefully you learn from this and your next question on stackoverflow will already contain all the requirements. By the way: you have not specified the values in the additional column at rows not being multiple of 10 ... or not being 10, so your requirements are still not clear.

Comment: Not clear is also if you need a value at row 20, 30, ... and if yes which one: the cumulative one or one from 11 to 20?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apply the `.sum()` method directly to a Pandas Series being a DataFrame column ( `how_many_times1.sum()` ). And because True is equivalent to 1 and False to 0 you can directly count the entries without applying a condition.
This makes sense in case you need the total sum. In case you need the sum periodically each ten rows it makes sense to count the True values in the to the column applied function.
The code below defines two 'apply' functions which do the job of creating the right entries for the columns and printing the sum each ten rows.

See the code below for how it is done in detail:

```
import pandas as pd   
df = pd.DataFrame([['20220901-00:00:00', 50.0335], 
                   ['20220901-00:00:01', 50.100 ], 
                   ['20220901-00:00:02', 48.021 ], 
                   ['20220901-00:00:01', 50.100 ], 
                   ['20220901-00:00:01', 50.100 ], 
                   ['20220901-00:00:02', 48.021 ], 
                   ['20220901-00:00:01', 50.100 ], 
                   ['20220901-00:00:01', 50.100 ], 
                   ['20220901-00:00:02', 48.021 ], 
                   ['20220901-00:00:01', 50.100 ], 
                   ['20220901-00:00:02', 48.021 ], 
                   ['20220901-00:00:01', 50.100 ], 
                   ['20220901-00:00:01', 50.100 ], 
                   ['20220901-00:00:01', 50.100 ]], 
                    columns=['t',          'f'  ])
columns = ['dummy', 'f<49.975','f>50.025']
print(df)

row1 = 1
sum1 = 0
lsm1 = []
def cond1(x):
    global row1, sum1
    cond = False
    if x < 49.975:
       cond=True
       sum1+=1
    if row1%10==0:
        print('sum1:', sum1, 'at row:', row1)
        lsm1.append(sum1)
        sum1=0 # outcomment if cummulative sum required
    else: 
        lsm1.append(None)
    row1 += 1
    return cond     
row2 = 1
sum2 = 0
lsm2 = []
def cond2(x):
    global row2, sum2
    cond = False
    if x > 50.025:
       cond=True
       sum2+=1
    if row2%10==0:
        print('sum2:', sum2, 'at row:', row2)
        lsm2.append(sum2)
        sum2=0 # outcomment if cummulative sum required
    else: 
        lsm2.append(None)
    row2 += 1
    return cond

how_many_times1 = df['f'].apply(cond1)
df[columns[1]]  = how_many_times1
df['sum1']      = lsm1
how_many_times2 = df['f'].apply(cond2)
df[columns[2]]  =how_many_times2
df['sum2']      = lsm2
print(df)
```

prints

```
                    t        f
0   20220901-00:00:00  50.0335
1   20220901-00:00:01  50.1000
2   20220901-00:00:02  48.0210
3   20220901-00:00:01  50.1000
4   20220901-00:00:01  50.1000
5   20220901-00:00:02  48.0210
6   20220901-00:00:01  50.1000
7   20220901-00:00:01  50.1000
8   20220901-00:00:02  48.0210
9   20220901-00:00:01  50.1000
10  20220901-00:00:02  48.0210
11  20220901-00:00:01  50.1000
12  20220901-00:00:01  50.1000
13  20220901-00:00:01  50.1000
sum1: 3 at row: 10
sum2: 7 at row: 10
                    t        f  f<49.975  sum1  f>50.025  sum2
0   20220901-00:00:00  50.0335     False   NaN      True   NaN
1   20220901-00:00:01  50.1000     False   NaN      True   NaN
2   20220901-00:00:02  48.0210      True   NaN     False   NaN
3   20220901-00:00:01  50.1000     False   NaN      True   NaN
4   20220901-00:00:01  50.1000     False   NaN      True   NaN
5   20220901-00:00:02  48.0210      True   NaN     False   NaN
6   20220901-00:00:01  50.1000     False   NaN      True   NaN
7   20220901-00:00:01  50.1000     False   NaN      True   NaN
8   20220901-00:00:02  48.0210      True   NaN     False   NaN
9   20220901-00:00:01  50.1000     False   3.0      True   7.0
10  20220901-00:00:02  48.0210      True   NaN     False   NaN
11  20220901-00:00:01  50.1000     False   NaN      True   NaN
12  20220901-00:00:01  50.1000     False   NaN      True   NaN
13  20220901-00:00:01  50.1000     False   NaN      True   NaN
```

Comment: It helps me with the sum of the word true but I need it to count every 10 rows not the total

Comment: The updated answer prints the sum values at row 10 and would print them also at row 20, 30, ... if there were any.

Comment: So ... there are the additional columns there ... faster than you are able to specify which values they should contain, so I decided to assign None ( NaN ) to rows not being multiple of ten.

Comment: I am working the code but I need it to be printed on the CSV and not on the screen, thank you very much and sorry for asking wrong, they are my first post and it costs me a little.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be:

```py
df[["f<49.975", "f>50.025"]] = (
    df.assign(f1=df["f"].lt(49.975), f2=df["f"].gt(50.025))
    .groupby(df.index // 10)[["f1", "f2"]].transform("sum")
    .loc[df.index % 10 == 9]
)
```

- Add two columns `f1`, `f2` to `df`, defined by the two conditions.
- Now group every 10 rows and sum over the two new columns to get the truth-count per block. Use `.transform` to do that to keep the original index.
- Then take only every tenth row and assign the result to the two new columns.